# how to add more items to a multiprocessing queue while script in motion

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to learn multiprocessing with queue.

What I want to do is figure out when/how to "add more items to the queue" when the script is in motion.

The below script is the baseline I am working from:

```
import multiprocessing


class MyFancyClass:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def do_something(self):
        proc_name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
        print('Doing something fancy in {} for {}!'.format(
            proc_name, self.name))


def worker(q):
    obj = q.get()
    obj.do_something()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(queue,))
    p.start()

    queue.put(MyFancyClass('Fancy Dan'))
    queue.put(MyFancyClass('Frankie'))
    print(queue.qsize())

    # Wait for the worker to finish
    queue.close()
    queue.join_thread()
    p.join()
```

on line 26, the `Fancy Dan` inject works, but the `Frankie` piece doesn't.  I am able to confirm that `Frankie` does make it into the queue.  I need a spot where I can "Check for more items" and insert them into the queue as needed.  If no more items exist, then close the queue when the existing items are clear.

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: "Frankie does make it into the queue" - Frankie won't go to the Process

Comment: yes.  `queue.qsize()` does recognize `Frankie`,  but `Frankie` doesn't make it to the worker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make it clear:

- the target function `worker(q)` will be called just once in the above scheme. At that first call the function will suspend waiting the result from blocking operation `q.get()`. It gets the instance `MyFancyClass('Fancy Dan')` from the `queue`, invokes its `do_something` method and get finished.
- `MyFancyClass('Frankie')` will be put into the queue but won't go to the Process cause the process' target function is done.
- one of the ways is to read from the queue and wait for a signal/marked item which signals that queue usage is stopped. Let's say `None` value.

---

```
import multiprocessing


class MyFancyClass:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def do_something(self):
        proc_name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
        print('Doing something fancy in {} for {}!'.format(proc_name, self.name))


def worker(q):
    while True:
        obj = q.get()
        if obj is None:
            break
        obj.do_something()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(queue,))
    p.start()

    queue.put(MyFancyClass('Fancy Dan'))
    queue.put(MyFancyClass('Frankie'))
    # print(queue.qsize())
    queue.put(None)

    # Wait for the worker to finish
    queue.close()
    queue.join_thread()
    p.join()
```

The output:

```
Doing something fancy in Process-1 for Fancy Dan!
Doing something fancy in Process-1 for Frankie!
```

Comment: Hey Roman....thanks for the answer.  I have a question.  why are both "Process-1"?  Thanks

Comment: @arcee123, you have just ONE process (with a distinct name) and multiple queue items to be processed

Comment: ok.  I have a question to allow more than one process (POOL) to it.  I'll put it on another question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56688468/how-to-add-a-pool-of-processes-available-for-a-multiprocessing-queue

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is by changing worker to

```
def worker(q):
    while not q.empty():
        obj = q.get()
        obj.do_something()
```

The problem with your original code is that worker returns after doing work on one item on the queue. You need some sort of looping logic.

This solution is imperfect because empty() is not [reliable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.empty). Also will fail if the queue becomes empty before adding more items to it (the process will just return).

I would suggest using a [Process Pool Executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor).

[Submit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.submit) is pretty close to what you're looking for.