# How to add a pool of processes available for a multiprocessing queue

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am following a preceding question here:  [how to add more items to a multiprocessing queue while script in motion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56687113/how-to-add-more-items-to-a-multiprocessing-queue-while-script-in-motion)

the code I am working with now:

```
import multiprocessing


class MyFancyClass:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def do_something(self):
        proc_name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
        print('Doing something fancy in {} for {}!'.format(proc_name, self.name))


def worker(q):
    while True:
        obj = q.get()
        if obj is None:
            break
        obj.do_something()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(queue,))
    p.start()

    queue.put(MyFancyClass('Fancy Dan'))
    queue.put(MyFancyClass('Frankie'))
    # print(queue.qsize())
    queue.put(None)

    # Wait for the worker to finish
    queue.close()
    queue.join_thread()
    p.join()
```

Right now, there's two items in the queue.  if I replace the two lines with a list of, say 50 items....How do I initiate a POOL to allow a number of processes available. for example:

```
p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
```

where does that go?  I'd like to be able run multiple items at once, especially if the items run for a bit.
Thanks!

Comment: this is different. When we use a pool - we expect to distribute computing on some iterable of datasets. While passing a queue in this case may be applicable if a processes would use that queue "extensively" like reading and writing to it, in most cases - we pass an iterable

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, you *either* use `Pool` *or* `Process`(es) plus `Queue`s. Mixing both is a misuse; the `Pool` already uses `Queue`s (or a similar mechanism) behind the scenes.

If you want to do this with a `Pool`, change your code to (moving code to `main` function for performance and better resource cleanup than running in global scope):

```
def main():
    myfancyclasses = [MyFancyClass('Fancy Dan'), ...] # define your MyFancyClass instances here
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as p:
        # Submit all the work
        futures = [p.apply_async(fancy.do_something) for fancy in myfancyclasses]

        # Done submitting, let workers exit as they run out of work
        p.close()

        # Wait until all the work is finished
        for f in futures:
            f.wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This could be simplified further at the expense of purity, with the `.*map*` methods of `Pool`, e.g. to minimize memory usage redefine `main` as:

```
def main():
    myfancyclasses = [MyFancyClass('Fancy Dan'), ...] # define your MyFancyClass instances here
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as p:
        # No return value, so we ignore it, but we need to run out the result
        # or the work won't be done
        for _ in p.imap_unordered(MyFancyClass.do_something, myfancyclasses):
            pass
```

Yes, technically either approach has a slightly higher overhead in terms of needing to serialize the return value you're not using so give it back to the parent process. But in practice, this cost is pretty low (since your function has no `return`, it's returning `None`, which serializes to almost nothing). An advantage to this approach is that for printing to the screen, you generally don't *want* to do it from the child processes (since they'll end up interleaving output), and you can replace the `print`ing with `return`s to let the parent do the work, e.g.:

```
import multiprocessing

class MyFancyClass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def do_something(self):
        proc_name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
        # Changed from print to return
        return 'Doing something fancy in {} for {}!'.format(proc_name, self.name)

def main():
    myfancyclasses = [MyFancyClass('Fancy Dan'), ...] # define your MyFancyClass instances here
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as p:
        # Using the return value now to avoid interleaved output
        for res in p.imap_unordered(MyFancyClass.do_something, myfancyclasses):
            print(res)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note how all of these solutions remove the need to write your own `worker` function, or manually manage `Queue`s, because `Pool`s do that grunt work for you.

---

Alternate approach using `concurrent.futures` to efficiently process results as they become available, while allowing you to choose to submit new work (either based on the results, or based on external information) as you go:

```
import concurrent.futures

from concurrent.futures import FIRST_COMPLETED

def main():
    allow_new_work = True  # Set to False to indicate we'll no longer allow new work
    myfancyclasses = [MyFancyClass('Fancy Dan'), ...] # define your initial MyFancyClass instances here
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        remaining_futures = {executor.submit(fancy.do_something)
                             for fancy in myfancyclasses}
        while remaining_futures:
            done, remaining_futures = concurrent.futures.wait(remaining_futures,
                                                              return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)
            for fut in done:
                result = fut.result()
                # Do stuff with result, maybe submit new work in response

            if allow_new_work:
                if should_stop_checking_for_new_work():
                    allow_new_work = False
                    # Let the workers exit when all remaining tasks done,
                    # and reject submitting more work from now on
                    executor.shutdown(wait=False)
                elif has_more_work():
                    # Assumed to return collection of new MyFancyClass instances
                    new_fanciness = get_more_fanciness()
                    remaining_futures |= {executor.submit(fancy.do_something)
                                          for fancy in new_fanciness}
                    myfancyclasses.extend(new_fanciness)
```

Comment: ok.  FIrst of all, write a book.  I'll have it published for you.  ;)  .  Thanks so much.  Here's where I get stuck.  Unlike the process example, the `Pool` example you provided implies that `myfancyclasses` must be completely defined prior to the instantiation of `Pool`.  While this is running, I need to check for more `myfancyclasses` and manually say when I'm done checking for more `myfancyclasses`.  in Process, I can do that...how do I do this here?

Comment: @arcee123: In the first block of example code, you can remove the `p.close()` call (allowing you to continue submitting work to the pool), then, by whatever logic informs when to make more `MyFancyClass`es, create the new class, call `apply_async` to dispatch the work for it, and append the result of `apply_async` to the `list` of "futures" (technically a term from `concurrent.futures` and the executor framework, `Pool` calls them `AsyncResult`s). Personally, I think `concurrent.futures` (with `ProcessPoolExecutor` in this case) is more intuitive for this use pattern, but `Pool` works.

Comment: If the results of `MyFancyClass.do_something` inform the decision to create/dispatch new instances, then you'd have `do_something` return the necessary information, and call `.get()` instead of `.wait()` (`.get()` is just `.wait()` that also returns the result, or raises the exception if the task died with an unhandled exception). Your "declaration" that you're done checking for more `MyFancyClass`es is mostly a matter of your own logic (just stop checking), but if you can readily identify when you reach that point, you'd call `p.close()` then, to let workers exit when they run out of tasks.

Comment: Side-note: In more complex cases (where you want to retrieve the result from whichever futures complete first, regardless of order), you definitely want to switch to `concurrent.futures`; Aside from `imap_unordered`, `Pool`s don't offer a clean way to get the first completed result from N futures. With `concurrent.futures`, you can make a `set` (not a `list`) of the futures, then do a loop while the `set` isn't empty calling `concurrent.futures.wait(futures, return_when=concurrent.futures.FIRST_COMPLETED)` to eagerly get results as they become available. I'll add a brief example to my answer.

Comment: one thing I have in my favor, is that I do not need to pass data from one task to the next.  I have two oracle tables that I compare, and if there's differences, I call the worker for that difference.  but the tables update over time, so as such when a new "difference" has been noted, I fire the worker again.